# Selected item is not synchronizing with selected items - a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

How can it be that `SelectedItem` is null and `SelectedItems` have an item selected?

Here's the screenshot from selection changed event:

[image]

My DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid SelectionChanged="CustomCmdDg_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentX,Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}" x:Name="CustomCmdDg"  ItemsSource="{Binding xList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
```

...
In my ViewModel:

`xList`= a list of class x (observable collection)

```
  private x currentX;

    public x CurrentX
    {
        get { return currentX; }
        set
        {
            currentX = null;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentX");
        }
    }
```

Purposely wanted that selected item will be null

Comment: Could you provide some code, your bindings, code behind

Comment: Paste `ViewModel`'s code

Comment: It is possible that the list contain null element

Comment: It's not in the list, this in the variable .. The goal is that no item will be selected

Comment: And if I put something else to SelectedItem, which was also found in the list, it is still different from SelectedItems. In Items I get what pressed from the UI compared to the item that also changes by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your currentitem to null you should first remove it from the collection, then it will be gone from the selected items:

```
Public ObservableCollection<x> xList

public x CurrentX
{
    get { return currentX; }
    set
    {
        xList.Remove(currentX)
        currentX = null;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentX");
    }
}
```

Your observable list will update itself

If you need to be able to manipulate the `SelectedItems` collection you will have to provide a binding as well and peform the code required

Comment: I do not want the item removed from the list, I just want him to not choose / change by code

Comment: I do not want to control the selected items, it seems illogical that they are not synchronized with the selected item.

Comment: they are synced when this happens from your UI, not from code behind

Comment: So the only way they will be synchronized code behind it to control the selected items?

Comment: You can try adding: NotifyPropertyChanged("xList"); This will trigger an update on your Observable collection

Comment: This ObservableCollection is doing it himself. And the NotifyPropertyChanged call only when I apply a new collection